# Making my home button work with history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, browser-history, history.js

I'm not grasping the concept of history.js. If someone can help me understand this in ELI5 terms, it would really help me out. I have a logo that is linked to the home button like this:

```
<h1 class="site-title">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home" data-title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo" height="89" width="70">
  </a>
</h1>
```

And here is the function to push the state to the history:

```
$('.site-title a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  History.pushState(null, site.title, site.url);

  // Some things that happen when I hit the home button
  $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
  $('article.project').removeClass('grayscale grayscale-fade').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Outside of that function, I have this (using history.js):

```
var History = window.History;

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){
    var State = History.getState();
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

Since my home link has an e.preventDefault, how do I actually make it go to the home page and have the user be able to hit the back button and have it all function correctly? Right now, when I click the button, it just pushes the page to the history stack.

Comment: Creating something that runs via the history API can be a lot more complex than you think. The idea is that on the click event you'll be simultaneously pushing a new 'state' to history.js *and* loading in your home content somehow. History.js doesn't do this for you. All history API does is gives you data to reference what you should be displaying based on where you are in the browser history.

Comment: @Jesse Thank you. That helps. I guess I'm stuck on the part where I have to figure out how to load in my home content. I'm doing this through Ajax so am I supposed to be calling Ajax within the click event? Do I add anything to the last code block?

Comment: You'll need that ajax load of content to be triggered 2 ways: once when you actually fire the pushState and again when a popstate fires. I notice that you leave the first parameter as null when you're pushing the state. That parameter is important because that's where you'll be placing unique identifying data which you'll use to decide what you're loading when `onpopstate` fires.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of moving pieces when you start working with the history api, but a simple example holds 3 main parts.

1. the inital page load, where we either generate the page server-side or use some sort of marker to load it client side ( like the url ).
2. The pseudo page load that happens on an user event ( click, etc ). This event needs to fire the push state as well as load the content to be displayed.
3. The pseudo page load that happens on a history event ( onpopstate, statechange ). The only data you'll have available to you is the data you stored when you previously pushed the state.

A really simple example with some dummy code:

Page load:

```
//since you're using the history.js
var History = window.History;

/*the state data is really important, as you'll need it when you 
  come back to this original state to know what to load */
Var initialData = { pageId : <current page ID> };

//we replace the state because the initial page load state doesn't have our data
History.replaceState(initialData, <initialTitle>, <initialUrl>);
```

setup our loadPage function

```
function loadPage(pageId){
   //grab page data based on unique identifier
   $.post('yourserver.whatever', { ID : pageId }, function(resp){
      // put your content where it needs to go
      $('<main content section>').html(resp);
   });
};
```

user event

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
   var newData = { pageId : <next page ID> };

   //should generally match link href with state url
   History.pushState( newData, <next page Title>, $(this).attr('href') );
   loadPage(newData.pageId);
});
```

history event

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){
    var State = History.getState();
    loadPage(State.data.pageID);
});
```

That is a very basic implementation of the history API, and I skimmed over a bunch of small things. There are a bunch of potential pitfalls to look out for, especially things like:

- Some browsers fire a popstate on page load, which is something you'll have to account for/deal with ( since you're using a compatibility library most of these bugs should be smoothed out ).
- Do you want a system that absolutely needs javascript to function, or will you account for lack of javascript support?
- Ajax call performance, ensuring that previously bound events are rebound if content is refreshed, etc, etc etc.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. Would it be possible to use the elements in my code in your example? I think the dummy code is throwing me off.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't really understand what you want to achieve, but shouldn't you just remove the `e.preventDefault()` statement? Or otherwise do something like this (look at the last line, where I explcitly send the user over):

```
$('.site-title a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    History.pushState(null, site.title, site.url);

    // Some things that happen when I hit the home button
    // ... do that stuff

    // and explicitly send the visitor to your homepage
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After you are done doing all of your 'things' in the `$('.site-title a').on('click', ...` function you can assign the home link to the `window.location` to navigate there.

```
$('.site-title a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  History.pushState(null, site.title, site.url);

  // Some things that happen when I hit the home button
  $('#project-wrapper').removeClass('activated').css('max-height', '');
  $('article.project').removeClass('grayscale grayscale-fade').css('opacity', '1');

  //perform the page navigation now
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```